# Place imageview to center

Tags: android

I want to place an arrow to my listview.

I am trying but,I didn't do it.Here is my result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

This is a lisview.And this is my source code of items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:paddingBottom="4dp"
              android:paddingTop="4dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tweet"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#0A0A14" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form"
            android:textColor="#474747" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/anchor" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I place the arrow to center ? And  I have one more question.Why arrow looking big and blurry in above image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow should be in the outer LinearLayout. You put it in the vertical LinearLayout, but is should be part of the horizontal LinearLayout

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
 android:src="@drawable/anchor" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much,it worked.I have one more question,user profile picture is 70x70 px in fireworks.What should be in android dp system for getting same result.

Comment: that depends on you. If you want 70 px to be the resolution for xhdpi drawable, then you should scale the other by a factor, and use dpi in your layout. The factor are 1 for mdpi, 1.5 for hdpi and 2 for xhdpi. So 1 px is 1 dip in mdpi, 1.5 px in hdpi and 2 px in xhdpi

Comment: Thank you,last question:Do you know why anchor and profile pictures are looking blurry ?

Comment: it is difficult to say. In what device are you shown those?

Comment: I am using Nexus 5 in Genymotion

Comment: nexus 5 is xhdpi. Try to use 32dip instead of 64dp

Comment: I am so confused now.How can I support multiple screens ? I will write different xml for each device ?

Comment: no you don't have to. Have you read the android's guide line about supporting multiple devices ?

Comment: Yes but I didn't understand it,do you know another guide ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not... I am sorry